# Pagination Using cassandra Database with php

Tags: php, pagination, cassandra

Please help me any one.how to use pagination in php with cassandra database.

Comment: I've found this, look if that can help somehow. https://github.com/jbohman/logsandra/wiki/Pagination-in-Cassandra

Comment: Take a look at "column count", should be very useful for pagination

Comment: Maybe you should add some information _what_ you want to paginate? But I think as long as you don't state explicitely it's rows everybody will most likely assume you want to paginate a row's columns (as rows aren't really sortable)?

Comment: Well I had the same problem, but I was using Java,
I figured it out with the help of this
http://usefultechnotes.blogspot.in/2012/03/pagination-with-cassandra.html